# Rotation angle of a giant water lily when a child crawls on its rim

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Below is a picture of Giant Water Lily. Scientific Name: Victoria Amazonica. Leaves of some of these could be as big as 3 m diameter and carry a weight of 45kg spread evenly and can support a child. Now the problem:

Suppose that a leaf of such flower with a child is floating freely on water. Child crawls along the edge of the leaf until it arrives back to the starting point. In other words, he makes a full circle in the reference frame of the leaf. Question:

What is the total angle $\theta $ that the leaf turns through in time child crawls? (in the reference frame of water). Assume that the leaf is a large rigid circular disk. Ignore air and water resistance.

**Edit:**

ftiaronsem's solution is absolutely correct if we assume that the leaf can only freely rotate about its geometrical center. However i was keeping in an eye that the leaf is not connected to the ground and can freely move in any direction.

Data given:

$m$ (mass of child)
$M$ (mass of the leaf)

[image: Giant Water Lily]

Comment: It's not obvious to me that there is sufficient information to solve the problem.  How do we know that the answer does not depend on the particular way in which the child crawls?

Comment: @Mark: can you illustrate how could the answer depend on that way?

Comment: @Marek I don't think it does, after thinking about it more.  I was just saying that it wasn't obvious to me - I didn't know whether it was true or not.  Anyway I think I might have a solution now simply in terms of $m$ and $M$.

Comment: @Mark: yes, I also think answer should be pretty simple and based just on conservation principles. Not as simple as my first comment here though. I didn't think about the problem properly then, just provided a first sketch :-)

Comment: @Martin I thought this question was either trivial if you assume the lily can't translate, or pointless grunt work if you assume it can.  Then I tried to solve it.  Gladly I was wrong in my original assessment.  +1

Answer (score 13):

**Note:** to illustrate the motion of the pad more clearly, I made [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqCjbo-Ua2M).

Let the pad have radius $R$.

Imagine looking down on the pad from above.  The baby is on the right, crawling counterclockwise.

The center of mass of the (baby + pad) system can't move.  In the picture below, the green circle represents the starting position of the pad.  The starting position of the baby is marked with an arrow pointing in the direction of its motion.  $C$ is the center of the pad, pointing in its direction of motion (opposite the baby's by conservation of momentum).  $M$ is the center of mass of the system.  $d = R\frac{m}{m+M}$ is the distance from the center of the pad to the center of mass of the system.

[image]

As time goes on, the baby moves around the edge, and the lily pad moves to stay perfectly opposite the baby.  This ensures that the center of mass doesn't move.  Because the length $d$ is fixed, $C$ must always stay the same distance from $M$, so $C$ must move in a circle around $M$.  The baby moves in another circle of radius $R-d$ so that the distance between the center of the pad and the baby remains $R$.  We can draw in the trajectories of the point $C$ and the baby, and add a radius, like this:

[image]

Together, the baby and the center of the pad have only one degree of freedom.  Either of them can choose to be at any given point on their trajectories, but the other one is then forced to be opposite them.  Let's describe their positions by an angle $\theta$ from the horizontal.  To show this, I'll move the baby up a bit and draw in $\theta$.

[image]

The lily pad has one more degree of freedom - its rotation.  Let's call its rotation relative to the water (relative to north) $\phi$.

The total angular momentum of the system is zero.  There are contributions from the translational angular momentum of the pad and the baby, and the rotational angular momentum of the pad.  This gives

$$Md^2\dot{\theta} + m(R-d)^2\dot{\theta} + \frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\phi} = 0$$

Simplifying the algebra using the expression for $d$, then integrating over time and using the initial condition $\phi(0) = \theta(0) = 0$, we get

$$\phi = \frac{-2m}{m+M}\theta$$

$\phi$ is what we're after, but we want to know $\phi$ after the baby has crawled far enough to return to its starting point.  The minus sign on $\phi$ indicates that the pad spins counter to the rotation of pad and baby around the center of mass.

To find $\phi$, we need to use the information about the total amount the baby crawls.  Introduce a new angle $\alpha$ that represents how much the baby has crawled around the pad from the pad's point of view - we are done when the baby gets to $\alpha = 2\pi$.

The true speed of the baby (relative to the water) is $(R-d)\dot{\theta}$.  Another way to calculate this is to find the baby's speed relative to the pad, then add the pad's speed relative to the water.  We don't need to worry about vectors here because all motion is tangent to the baby's trajectory.  This gives

$$(R-d)\dot{\theta} = R\dot{\alpha} + R \dot{\phi} - d\dot{\theta}$$

(**note:** I originally left out the term $R \dot{\phi}$, which led the initial answer to be off) This simplifies to

$$\theta = \alpha + \phi$$

again using the initial condition $\theta(0) = \alpha(0) = 0$.  We want $\alpha = 2\pi$, so set $\theta = 2\pi + \phi$.  After simplifying, this gives the final answer

$$\phi = \frac{-4\pi m}{3m+M}$$

Comment: Sorry about double-using $M$ for pad mass and point of the center of mass.  I don't really want to go back and re-do all the pictures.  I hope it doesn't cause too much confusion.

Comment: If the child is infinitely heavy, you should get a rotation of $2\pi$, but this results gives $4\pi$. =/

Comment: @Bruce That is not the case.  What is your justification?

Comment: @mark: My mistake. If the child is infinitely heavy, then it will stay in place as the plant spins. But I just realised: the plant will turn around the kid AND turn around its own axis. Each of these rotations will be $2\pi$, summing to a total of $4\pi$. So your limit matches.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution. I have some questions about it: In the equation: $Md^2\dot{\theta} + m(R-d)^2\dot{\theta} + \frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\phi} = 0$ you use $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ for what exactly? $m(R-d)^2\dot{\theta}$ is the angular momentum of the child and the angular momentum of the disk is $\frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\phi}$. So I guess $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ is the moment of Inertia of the rotation of the entire system around the center of mass. However if this is the case the Moment of Inertia schould rather be something like $\frac{Md^2 + \frac{1}{2}MR^2 + m(R-d)^2}{m+M}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could you please be more specific of how you define $\phi$? As Bruce said it would be the sum of the angle through which the flower rotates around the center of mass of the system + the angle through which the disk spins. However based on the comments below my answer, I thought we had agreed that the angle we are searching for is the angle the leaf spins through (See your comment about the notch). This angle could never be larger than $2\pi$ since the bayby would stop at that moment.

Comment: @ftiaronsem $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ is the angular momentum of the pad due to its translation across the surface of the pond.  $1/2*MR^2\dot{\phi}$ is the angular momentum of the pad due to its rotation about its center.  You might want to read this section on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Angular_momentum_simplified_using_the_center_of_mass

Comment: @ftiaronsem $\phi$ is the angle the leaf spins through, as I was describing with the notch.  There is no reason for the baby to stop when $\phi = 2\pi$.  The baby stop when it gets back to the same spot on the pad.   That is different than stopping when the pad has rotated a full rotation with respect to the water.

Comment: @Bruce Nice!  Very concise explanation of why that limit works.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: *(about the limit of the obese child)* I wasn't perfectly clear. The angle that the pad turns around its own axis is indeed $4\pi$. The individual contributions will be: $2\pi$ because the plant spins around the child with one edge fixed; and $2\pi$ because the child walks until the circumference has gone around once.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: One rotation maintains a fixed edge, and spins the CM. The other keeps the CM fixed and rotates the perimeter around it. The sum of these effects move both the CM and the edge, and sums up to $4\pi$.

Comment: The way I said it earlier sounded like the angle the pad turned around its axis was one of the contributions towards the final result, which is wrong.

Comment: @Mark: Your first equation is totally wrong! The law of conservation of angular momentum for this system must be expressed as  $I_m\omega_m + I_M\omega_M=0$ where $I_m$ and $I_M$ are the moments of inertia of the child and the pad about the axis which passes through the center of the mass of the whole system and $\omega_m$ and $\omega_M$ are corresponding angular velocities in the reference frame of the ground (or stationary water). More specifically, $\omega_M$ is angular velocity of the center of the pad.

Comment: @Martin It isn't wrong.  I included what you said, but you are forgetting that we need to include the angular momentum of the pad's translation as well as the angular momentum of the pad's spinning.

Comment: @Mark. Ok I why you are writing $Md^2\dot{\theta}$, however I am still not convinced ;-). Cite from Wikipedia: $L=R\text{ x }MV+\sum_i r_i\text{ x }m_iv_i$. The first term is obviously $0$, since the center of mass is not moving in our case. So you have to sum all the $r_i\text{ x }m_iv_i$. In our case this is simply the sum of $r_i^2m_i\omega_i$, where $\omega_i$ is the angular velocity, of the $i$th particle relative to the center of mass. In our case there are two parts moving around the center of mass. The pads translation and the childs translation.......... (see next comment)

Comment: @Mark. For the child we have the moment of inertia of $m(R-d)^2$, for the pads translation we have the moment of inertia of $Md^2 + \frac{1}{2}MR^2$. So according to wikipedia this would become $m(R-d)^2\omega_m + Md^2 + \frac{1}{2}MR^2 \omega_m$ This becomes: $(m(R-d)^2 + Md^2 + \frac{1}{2}MR^2) \omega_m$ and not simply $Md^2\dot{\theta}$. This is what I wanted to point out with my first comment. Sorry for me dividing the expression in my old post by $m+M$, which is a mistake I made in a hurry.

Comment: @ftiaronsem  Well, you're making progress, but you're still missing the basic point.  You can't just give the pad a moment of inertia and say that its angular momentum is $I\omega$.  That would only work if the pad were rotating around a fixed point, but it's not.  It's going in circles around one point and rotating around another point.  The point of the wikipedia link was that I'm calculating the angular momentum of the pad with the equation you quoted from Wikipedia.  The first part, $R\times MV$ is not zero because the center of mass of the pad moves.  It gives the term $M d^2\dot{\theta}$

Comment: The second part is that summation, and is $R^2*M/2*\dot{\phi}$.  So I was not trying to apply that equation to the entire system at once.  You can do that, but you have to be more careful about that summation.  You need to sum each part of the lily, and they're all moving at different speeds.  If you want to apply that equation to the whole system at once, you'll need to write down an expression for the speed of every part of the lily in terms of $\dot{\theta}$ and $\dot{\phi}$ and integrate over all the mass.  It's much easier just to do the lily and baby separately.

Comment: Well, the translational part of the pad is indeed rotating around a fixed point, the center of mass. That is why I wrote $Md^2 + \frac{1}{2}MR^2$, according to the parallel axis thoerem. I am aware that the spinning part has to be calculated differently. And Wikipedia is saying: "... the angular momentum of a collection of particles about their center of mass ...", so by using Wikipedias formula you are calculating the rotation of the system around its center of mass. Not the rotation about the center of mass of the pad.

Comment: To your second comment: "You need to sum each part of the lily, and they're all moving at different speeds" Isn't that exactly what the parallel axis thoerem does?

Comment: @ftiaronsem The parallel axis theorem is not applicable here.  I would try to explain it again, but it is clear that you need more detail than I can provide in a comment thread.  I suggest grabbing a textbook on mechanics.  Taylor's "Classical Mechanics" is good.  As I recall, you want chapter 8.

Comment: @ftiaronsem I looked it up and it's actually chapter 10.  These two pages should be enough: http://goo.gl/NvMeX

Comment: @Mark. Thank you very much. I will look into it soon.

Comment: @Mark: +1 for the video :D Which programs did you use?

Comment: @Mark. Very nice video, indeed. However in the last time I got more and more convinced that my last answer might be correct nevertheless. This is because the pad is doing a translational motion, but the center of mass of the system remains fixed. This is why I can use the parallel axis theorem to fully describe that motion. The translational part is somewhat included in these calculations. For example: See all that classical tasks in which you have a rigid body rotating around a fixed pole. The geometrical center of all these rigid bodys have a translational motion.

Comment: However their motion is being described by the parallel axis theorem. I would very much love to discuss this problem in person, however based on you profile we are a few thousend kilometers away. Simply by writing we probably might not reach a conlcusion. Do you have a VoIp programm like skype?

Comment: @Robert The program is Geogebra.  It's very easy to learn.  http://www.geogebra.org/cms/

Comment: @ftiaronsem Your hang-up is a misunderstanding of the parallel axis theorem.  It is not applicable here.  I understand the parallel axis theorem.  I have derived it myself several times.  I have taught it to people.  I have used it to solve plenty of problems.  But it simply is not applicable here.  It should be quite obvious after watching the video that the pad has two degrees of freedom - a "spin" rotation and an "orbital" rotation.  Isn't it obvious that calculating the angular momentum must depend on both of these, not just one?  If you are available now, we can use the chat feature.

Comment: @Mark. Thank you so much, I indeed learned a lot from you. I watched the video and read the book chapter and to sum it up: I am indeed wrong. I'll make some calculations right now, to fully comprehend my missunderstanding and the new situation. I'll come back this afternoon and rewrite my initial answer. Probably also having a bunch of further questions ;-) Thank you very much for holding on this issue over dozens of comments until now.

Comment: I'm satisfied this is correct, but it violates my intuition that a massless lily should do all the moving and so give phi = -2pi instead of -4pi/3. A mystery.

Answer (score 9):

This first part asumes the following two things:

1) The flower is connected to the ground, i.e. by its shaft, so that its center of mass is not moving.

2) The child stops as soon as it reaches it's original position on the flower (Not its original position in the ground reference frame).

As Marek correctly pointed out:

$I\omega_l=mR^2\omega_c$

where $I$ is the Moment of Inertia of the flower, $w_l$ its angular velocity, $R$ its Radius and where $\omega_c$ ist the angular velocity of the child.

This can directly be derived from the conservation of angular momentum.

By integrating this over the time $t$ the child is crawling, you get:

$I\int_0^t\omega_l=mR^2\int_0^t\omega_c$

$I\omega_lt=mR^2\omega_c t $

Now, one might be tempted to think that $ \omega_ct = 2 \pi$. However this is not true (Credits go to Sklivvz), since the flower is also spinning. However we know that $w_ct + w_lt = 2\pi$:

$I\omega_lt=mR^2(2\pi - \omega_lt) $

$I\omega_lt + m R^2 \omega_lt =mR^22\pi $

Now by knowing that the moment of inertia of a disk is $\frac{M}{2}R^2$ (I can add a prove if you want me to), we get:

$\frac{M}{2}R^2 \omega_lt + m R^2 \omega_lt =mR^22\pi $

$\frac{M}{2} \theta + m \theta =m2\pi $

$M \theta + 2m \theta =m4\pi $

$\theta=\frac{m4\pi}{M+2m}$

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

As discussed in the comments, not only the child has an angular velocity around the center of mass, but the entire system is rotating around the center of mass.

[image: flower rotating around its center of mass]

In my first attempt to solve this general case of the problem (which I have deleted due to it being nonsense), I assumed that the translational part of the flower is covered by applying the parallel axis theorem. However, as Mark pointed out correctly, the parallel axis theorem is not applicable here. For a detailed explanation watch Mark's great video and read through the book chapter he linked in the comments.

Please see Mark's Post for a detailed and correct analysis of this situation.

Comment: This is incorrect: $\omega_c$ as you write it is w/r/t lily. The correct expression w/r/t water is $\omega_c'=\omega_c+\omega_l$. The correct expression is then $\theta=\frac{m}{M-2m}\pi$ which sensibly predicts only a 180 degrees turn if both masses are the same.

Comment: ohh, you are perfectly right, I should have checked that result. I will correct it shortly.

Comment: well at least you are partialy right I think. I don't know how you get to $\theta=\frac{m}{M-2m}\pi$. I think the disk turning 180 degrees would only be correct if the entire mass of the disk would be at his edge. However since the mass distribution is homogenues I think it makes sense, that the disk is moving more than 180 degrees, in case both masses are equal. After all the mass elements nearer at the center have a lower contribution to the moment of inertia.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Take your first equation. The left hand side contains the angular momentum of the plant in the ground reference frame. Therefore, the right hand side (which contains the child's angular momentum) must also be written in the ground reference frame. That means $\omega_c$ (as you defined) is the angular velocity in the ground reference frame. I think your original calculation was correct: $t\omega_c = 2\pi$.

Comment: In fact, the original result made more sense, because an infinitely heavy child would spin the plant indefinitely ($\theta = \infty$) and never finish the lap.

Comment: Haha ;-) Nice, three people three opinions^^. I love physics. Is there any chance of anybody making that experiment? ;-) Taking my first result with equal masses, the disk would have spun around $4\pi$, which is definitly incorrect. I think the problem is that the child is indeed not moving with $w_c$ in the ground reference frame. You can think of the disk spinning away below the child, as it crawls. Therefore $w_ct=2\pi$ is only true if $w_c$ would be the relative velocity of the child compared to the disk (As it is for example in the reference frame of the flower).

Comment: Ahh, wait now i relice what you ment. No, the child is not crawling a circle. It is just crawling until it reaches its starting point. Thats the difference. You assumed the first, I the latter. From the task, you can read that the child crawls until reaching his starting point. (I do not believe that the child is aware of the ground reference frame, so it will be contempt as it reaches its point of origin on the plant ^^)

Comment: It seems like this answer assumes that the lily is spinning while sitting in one place.  If that's so, the child is moving with respect to the water while the lily's center of mass is not, and therefore the center of mass of the whole system accelerates.  The leaf ought to move some across the surface of the water.  It's not immediately obvious to me whether this affects the rotation.

Comment: uhh, correct. And I always believed in the simplicity of classical mechanics. Based on these comments I have written a list of assumptions I making before the calculation. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ftiaronsem Oh! I see what you mean! Reading it that way, then your answer is correct indeed. I guess the question is not perfectly clear. Actually, I completely read the question wrong^^. The asker clearly means it your way.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: The assumption "The flower is connected to the ground, i.e. by its shaft, so that its center of mass is not moving." is incorrect. The flower can floate freely!(Read the problem description) This makes your solution wrong.

Comment: @Martin If you meant for the plant's movement to be completely free, then your question needs to be reworded a little. You just ask for $\theta$ so it gives the impression you're only interested in rotation. If you allow the plant to float completely free, then it's a lot more complicated, and you need to define at least 3 variables just for the plant. Edit your answer to specify this

Comment: hmm, ok. Lets say the flower can float freely. Then the flower would not rotate round its geometrical center, but around the center of mass, which would be somewhere between the child and the geometrical center of the flower. So basically two things would happen: 1) The Moment of Inertia of the plant changes (Can be easily calculated by the parallel axis theorem) and 2) the Moment of Inertia of the child would be time dependent (ugh). The rest would remain the same, wouldn't it? Please give me feedback on that. If a reasonable number of you agrees, I will make the necessary calculations.

Comment: However shouldn't you better ask for the angle in the reference frame of the center of mass, instead of the center of the flower in the case described above?

Comment: sorry, ment: "However shouldn't you better ask for the angle in the reference frame of the center of mass, instead of the anle in the reference frame of the water?" in my previous comment. Because if you really want to calculate the rotation of the flower in the reference frame of the water, you would indeed need more parameters as Bruce pointed out.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I don't know if the child's momento of inertia would be time dependant. Actually, this new problem might not be THAT complicated after all, you just need to find the right constraints. I might give it more thought later.

Comment: @ftiaronsem:If the disk turns an angle in the reference frame of the center of mass then it turns the same angle in the reference frame of the water.

Comment: @Martin: Well for the rotation of the flower it does. However the Flower itself (measured by its geometrical center) would change its position a bit.This is due the center of mass not remaining on a fixed position. Think of the starting position, and some position a time t later. The child would then have changed its postion in the reference frame of the water. Therefore the center of mass would also have changed, which results in the flower moving around on the water (Quite possibly in a circular motion). So one would have to be specific what angle to calculate. At least I think so...

Comment: @ftiaronsem I think it is pretty clear what the pad's angle of rotation means.  Make a little notch on the outside edge of the pad at North.  Have the child crawl around, then look at where the notch is compared to north.

Comment: @Mark: agreed, just wanted to point out, that there are more parameters, than just the pad's angle of rotation.

Comment: @All: Added a possible calculation of how to calculate $\theta$ for a free floating flower, so that we have something concrete to discuss.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Are you talking about the center of mass of the disk? I am talking about the center of mass of the whole system (disk+child). The disc(or its center of mass) rotates about the system's center. So if the disk turns an angle about the center of mass of the system then it turns the same angle in the reference frame of the water. Rotation angle is uniquely determined.

Comment: @ftiaronsem Why can you use the parallel axis theorem?  Doesn't that mean you're assuming that the pad rotates perfectly around the center of mass, as if there were a pole stuck through there instead of at the center of the pad?

Comment: @ftiaronsem:Your final expression can be greatly simplified. I think, i am agree with you. But there is a strange behaviour with this formula. There seems to be a maximum value for $\theta$.

Comment: @Martin: I totally agree and i suddenly reliced that there would be no additional motion of the center of mass. Sorry for that. The center of mass remains fixed, since there are no external forces applied to it. You are totally right. @Mark: this is why I can use the paralle axis theorem.

Comment: @ftiaronsem I was already aware that the center of mass doesn't move.  Having the center of mass be stationary is not the same as having the pad rotate about the center of mass.  Imagine the baby is on the right-hand side as you look down.  The baby starts crawling up, or counter-clockwise.  Then the pad's net acceleration is down and the right-hand side of the pad moves down more quickly.  Contrast this to spinning around the center of mass.  If the pad spun around the center of mass so that the net motion of the pad was down, the right hand side would be going up.

Comment: @Mark. I am sorry, I am not getting your point. If the child would crawl counter-clockwise, the net acceleration of the plant would be clockwise (Is this what you ment with down?). Why should the right hand site move faster? Isin't it exactly the opposite? $v=\omega r$. A point on the left hand site of the flower is further away from the center of mass, therefore his volicty would be larger.

Comment: @ftiaronsem If the baby crawls one way, then the entire pad must move the opposite way.  Further, if the baby has angular momentum about the center of mass of the system, then the pad must have opposite angular momentum about the center of mass of the system.  The result is that the pad moves in a circle around the center of mass, but that it rotates in the opposite direction that it moves.  If the pad goes around the center of mass counterclockwise, the pad rotates clockwise.

Comment: @Mark: "If the pad goes around the center of mass counterclockwise, the pad rotates clockwise." This i do not understand at all. By the way, why a downvote(at least at this stage).

Comment: @Martin The center of the pad moves in a circle around the center of mass going one way.  The pad rotates about its own center the other way.  I down voted because I think the answer is wrong.  If it changes or if I'm convinced I'm incorrect, I'll remove the down vote.

Comment: @Mark: There is no reason to rotate the pad about its own center while it rotates about the center of mass of the system. This contradicts to the conservation of angular momentum. Why not submit your own answer to the problem?

Comment: @Martin I am not quite done my answer.  The pad has three degrees of freedom - two translational and one rotational.  The two translational degrees of freedom are constrained to movement in a circle, because otherwise the center of mass of the system would move.  My claim is that to conserve angular momentum, if the translational degrees of freedom are making the pad circle around the center of mass counterclockwise, the rotational degree of freedom is rotating clockwise.  This is necessary to conserve angular momentum.

Comment: @Mark. Ok I understand what you mean and its perfectly correct. The geometrical center of the pad moves in a circle around the center of mass. And yeah, I think you convinced me of having to change that equation a bit. Do you agree that the angular velocity of the center of the pad is the same as the childs angular velocity? (has to be otherwise the center of mass would move). So instead of saying that the moment of inertia is $m(R-d)^2$ I would have to write $m(R-d)^2+I'$? Since not only the child is rotating around the center of mass but the flower as well. Do you agree?

Comment: @Martin. I think Mark is right about that. That pad is not rotating about its own center. The entire system is rotating around the center of mass (I believe). I will make some scatches to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @ftiaronsem I agree that the angular velocity of the child and of the geometrical center of the pad, both about the center of mass, are the same.  I am not sure I understand your meaning with the new moments of inertia.  Note that in addition to going in a circle around the center of mass, the pad is also spinning.  If you want to calculate its angular momentum, you need to take into account both motions.  The answer I have after doing this is that the pad rotates $2\pi(2m/(m+M))$.  I will post details either tonight or tomorrow morning, depending on how much energy I have.

Comment: I have added a picture depicting the situation. @Mark. I am looking forward to that.

Comment: @ftiaronsem Nice picture!

Comment: @ftiaronsem Nice picture! what did u use to create it?

Comment: Inkscape, its brilliant vector graphics programm: http://inkscape.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: @ftiaronsem Since the OP "accepted" your answer, it has the Physics.se stamp of approval.  I'd appreciate if you could change it to the correct answer at your earliest convenience.

Comment: @Mark. I adapted my answer and left additional comments. Sorry for not showing up lately but university kept me very busy. Is the adapted answer fitting for physics.se?

Comment: @ftiaronsem Thank you for updating your answer.  It's good that it now indicates that another analysis exists.  However, the current analysis in your answer is still incorrect, and the answer would be improved even more by giving it the correct physics.  Did you read the textbook link I gave, which describes how to calculate angular momentum?  Was any part of it unclear?  If you would like to visualize the motion, please check out the video I made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqCjbo-Ua2M

Comment: If you are unconvinced, please note that there is a gaping mismatch bettween the equation $I'\omega_l = m(R-d)^2\omega_c$ and illustrations you created.  If the child is going to rotate perfectly opposite the center of mass of the pad (which it must so that the center of mass of the system doesn't move), then $\omega_l = \omega_c$.  Everything would be rotating the same direction.  All the angular momentum would point the same direction - up out of the monitor as drawn in your pictures.  The only way to counter this is to have the pad spin the opposite direction.

Comment: Not to mention the equation has a sign error.  You don't want the angular momentum of the pad and the child to be equal to each other.  You want them to sum to zero.

Comment: Ohh, ok, I'll look into that this weekend, correct that mistake, read the textbook and update my answer. Its quite late at the moment ;-). thanks for all you efforts.

Comment: @ftiaronsem Okay, thanks for your efforts.  Where are you studying that it's so late?  (For me it is early afternoon on the US west coast.)

Comment: @Mark, yeah, well I am from Germany and it was about 23:30, at the time of that comment.^^ Definitly too late to give the problem a deep thought or even realizing that I might be wrong ;-)

Comment: @Martin: Please accept Mark's answer, since it is the correct solution to the general problem. Mine is indeed wrong for the general case. Watching the video and reading through the book chapter Mark provided, is really helpfull.

Comment: @Mark. Thank you so much. Did some calculations and realized my mistake. The book you linked is really excellent. I had never seen equation 10.9 before, although it is damn important and moreover very intuitive. I was really really wrong. I owe you a big one for removing this fundamental misconception from my head. You really are a great and patient teacher. There is just one question, I stumbled upon during the past hour, for which I would like to have confirmation:

Comment: Am I correct in saying that, for a system rotating around it's center of mass, I never have to use the parallel axis theorem? Formula 10.9 and the subsequent example seem to imply that. Therefore the parallel axis theorem would only be applicable in the case of an external fixed axis, like a nail, which is stuck through the rigid body. Is this correct?

Comment: @ftiaronsem Yes, your assessment of the parallel axis theorem is right.  I'm glad everything worked out - thanks for talking about the problem with me.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Unfortunately, i can not accept Mark's answer because it's solution in case of zero-mass pad  is contrary to the conservation of angular momentum in my opinion. But  i will be happy to discuss with you on this topic and if you can convince me that i'm incorrect then i accept Mark's solution.

Comment: @Martin: Why do you think angular Momentum is violated in case of a zero mass pad? The disk would spin around the child and rotate around itself. However the child would remain at the same place. Since the mass of the pad is zero, it has no angular momentum. Therefore angular momentum would be conserved.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: In case of a zero mass pad the center of mass of the system(pad+child) and the center of mass of the child coincide. If you assume that the child is a point mass (Mark's solution assumes) then the inertial moment of the system is exactly zero (inertial moment of a point mass is zero). The rotation of a body with zero inertial moment about its own axis is not defined. So in case of a zero mass pad we must assume that the child is not a point mass but have an infinitesimally small inertial moment(different from zero) and spatial dimensions. So if the pad spins around the child then

Comment: (continuation...) it rotates relative the child and the friction torque occurs. To keep the child non-rotating(because the angular momentum of the system is zero) we must assume an external torque which keeps the child non-rotating.

Comment: @Martin: There is no friction torque. In all our caculations, inclduing mine, we always assumed that there is no friction. You even say that yourself in the description of the problem: "Ignore air and water resistance". So there is no friction torque. Therefore angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: **There is friction between the child and the pad**. Without this friction the child can not crawl relative the pad and the problem loses its meaning.

Comment: @Martin. Thats definitly true, i didn't get that you ment the friction force between the baby and the pad. Ok. You say "The rotation of a body with zero inertial moment about its own axis is not defined". If so, why should the the inertial moment of the pad be defined? Since its mass is zero, its inertial moment is zero. Of course it is not rotating around its own axis, however that should make no difference. Therefore you would also be forced to give the pad some mass, which would make the thinking about a zero pad mass pointless.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I think that the thinking about a zero pad mass is not pointless. Mark's solution gives in this case for the angular displacement specific value: $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. But we can take the mass of the pad infinitesimally small, different from zero. The last value is practically the same. The physics does not change. But in case of zero-mass pad it is simply easier to analyze things. By the way, i read you're sure that to use the parallel axis theorem for a system rotating around it's center of mass is incorrect. Ok, let's consider a case where the rotation axis is fixed.(Continues...)

Comment: (connected to the ground) and passes the pad away from the center of the mass of the system. Now as I understand, you allow to use this theorem.  Now it comes a peculiar discontinuity. The theorem is applicable everywhere except at one point on the pad. Do you really believe this kind of discontinuity?

Comment: @Martin. Well, the parallel axis theorem can be used everywhere, even at the center of mass, as long as there is a fixed axis. However at the center of mass, it is pointless to use this theorem, since the distance $d$ between the axis of rotation and the center of mass is zero. Therefore $I` = I + md^2$ simplifies to $I` = I$. The problem with my answer was that I applied the parallel axis theorem to a case, where there use of this theorem is physical nonsense: My wrong consideration went as follows: (continued)

Comment: __The pad is rotating around the center of mass of the system. Since the center of mass is not equal to the geometrical center of the pad, the parallel axis theorem has to be applied.__ So far so bad. This consideration is wrong because: The pad is not rotating around the center of mass. The **center of mass of the pad** is rotating around **the center of mass of the system**. Additionally to this movement the pad is also spinning **around its center of mass**. (continued)

Comment: For the rotation of the center of mass of the pad around the center of mass of the system, I have to use $Md^2$ and for the spinning of the pad I have to use $\frac{MR^2}{2}$. Take a look at Marks answer. You will find these two expressions right in his first equation (The third term is describing the rotation of the child around the center of mass). As you can see there is no parallel axis theorem used. (continued)

Comment: No back to your argumentation: "But we can take the mass of the pad infinitesimally small, different from zero. The last value is practically the same." It is indeed nearly the same, but not quite. In the case of some inertial moment of the pad there is no contradiction at all. If the inertial moment of the pad is not zero, it has some angular momentum, while rotating. Therefore the child is also allowed to have some angular momentum. These momenta cancel exactly. Therefore angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I consider only the fundamental mistake made by you and Mark. You claim that the pad(a rigid body) has within itself at the same time two different rotation axes with different angular velocities. No, there is only one rotation axis: instantaneous axis of rotation which passes through the center of mass of the system and there is only one angular velocity about this axis. To split the rotational motion into two: the spinning and orbiting, makes sense only if the center of mass of the system is located outside the pad.

Comment: @Martin. Now we are getting to some point! We do not claim that a rigid body has two axis of rotation at the same time. As you say, a rigid boddy has only one rotation axis, this is perfectly correct. However the **sysytem** can have an axis of rotation and the **pad** can have an axis of rotation. These two can coexist. You already agree to that if the center of mass is outside the system, but this is also true if the center of mass is inside of the system. To argue in your words: Why should the law of physics change apruptly? (continued)

Comment: This would be a discontinuity! If you like a real world example take a look at this helicopter: http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/photos/uncategorized/2008/03/04/img_15141_2.jpg Of course both of its rotors are rotating. Additionally the helicopter could rotate around its center of mass (i.e. if someone would apply a torque on the rear end of the helicopter). In this case the helicopter would have three different rotations. All of them **inside** the system.

Comment: If you do not like the analogon with the helicopter take a look at the book chapter Mark linked. Look at the derivation of equation 10.8 and tell me: Where is the line the author is assuming that the rotational center is outside the system? You will find none...

Comment: I just noticed that I wrote "center of mass" being outside the system, in my first comment, this is bullshit. I ment the rotational center. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Ok, i start from the equation (10.8): $L=\vec{R}\times M\vec{\dot{R}}+\sum\vec{r'_a}\times m_a\vec{\dot{r'_a}}$. Now place origin $O$ inside the body in Figure 10.1. Imagine that the body is our pad. The pad rotates about the axis which passes through the origin. Let the angular velocity of $\vec{R}$ about the axis be $\vec{\omega}$. Because $\vec{R}\times \vec{\dot{R}}=\vec{\omega}R^2$ we can write the first term in the equation as $MR^2\vec{\omega}$. Now, the most important thing: Note from the figure that $\vec{R},\vec{r'_a}$ are fixed in the body and they can not (cont'd...)

Comment: move relative to each other. On the contrary, if the origin is placed outside the body you can move $\vec{r_a}$ relative $\vec{R}$ by rotating the first about the center of mass of the body because $\vec{R}$ is not fixed in the body. So, if the origin lies inside the body the second term in the equation may be written as $\sum\vec{\omega} m_ar'_a^2$ and the whole equation may be represent as $L=(MR^2+\sum m_ar'_a^2)\vec{\omega}$. The expression in brackets is not anything other than the parallel axis theorem. I think, everything is very simple and clear. A quote from Taylor:(cont'd...)

Comment: "The division of the total angular momentum into its orbital and spin parts is especially useful because it is often true(at least to a good approximation) that the two parts are separately conserved." Note that he does not claim that this splitting is always true. I'm back on Monday. Have a nice weekend:)

Comment: @Martin: Nice derivation of the parallel axis theorem, however you are again ignoring that we have multiple rigid bodies instead of one. If our system would consist of only the pad as a rigid body, you would be perfectly correct. In this case there could be only one axis of rotation. However as the number of involved objects increases there are more rotation axis allowed. (continued)

Comment: I say we even have **three** rigid bodies with there own axis of rotation in our system. The first rigid body is the pad. The second rigid body is the child. The third rigid body is the system of child+pad. The pad as a rigid body has a moment of inertia of $\frac{M}{2}R^2$. The child itself has no angular momentum, since it is a point mass. The system of the pad and the child has $Md^2 + m(R-d)^2$ as its moment of inertia. (continued)

Comment: I have also searched for another analogon, that might help you to accept that the pad is orbiting and spinning. Look at this spinning top: http://www.prismenfernglas.de/images/kreisel.jpg. It has a spinning part of its movement and a precession part.

Comment: I am aware that there are differences between a spinning top and our child pad system. But the core idea of what I am trying to explain can be illustrated by it. The spinning top is rotating around its shaft and the shaft itself has an orbital motion at the same time. As you can see from the picture, the axis of the orbital motion of the shaft is inside of the spinning top. This is possible because you have enough degrees of freedom. In our problem there are also enough degrees of freedom, for both motions to happen at the same time.

Comment: Note that the key issue is us having a system of multiple bodies and not just the pad.

Comment: @ftiaronsem:  quote from Wikipedia: "In mechanics, degrees of freedom (DOF) are the set of independent displacements and/or rotations that specify completely the displaced or deformed position and orientation of the body or system." You claim that there is three degrees of freedom in our system. Suppose that one degree say "orbital" degree of the pad is fixed. Can you now spin the pad independently about its geometrical axis? No, you can not until the "orbital" axis passes through the pad. In case of the spinning top the "orbital" and "spinning" motions are obviously independent.

Comment: @Martin. Hmm, I have difficulties understanding your point. What do you mean by one degree fixed? A constant orbital motion, with a certain angular velocity $w>0$? Furthermore you say "No, you can not until the 'orbital' axis passes through the pad", whereas you said in your previous comment: "On the contrary, if the origin is placed outside the body you can move $\vec{r_a}$ relative $\vec{R}$⃗  by rotating the first about the center of mass of the body because $\vec{R}$ is not fixed in the body". Please clarify, so that I am sure to get your point.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Yes, it was not the most successful comment maybe. I try to understand what is the main point in which our understandings differ fundamentally. We are both agreed that the center of mass of the system is stationary in RF of ground and the system rotates about the axis that passes through this center. Maybe the main point is that you split the motion of the pad into "orbital" and spinning" parts while i think that this splitting is unnecessary because i think that the pad rotates (as a whole) about the axis (that passes through center of the mass of the system) with unique (cont'd)

Comment: angular velocity. My understanding is that the axis is not fixed in the reference frame of the pad. It is so called "instantaneous axis of rotation". The axis passes the pad at a point around which all other points of the pad (for one instant) are rotating. This point itself is the only point that is not moving at that instant(in RF of ground). In this sense the axis is fixed relative the pad at this point at that instant and because the conservation of angular momentum must hold at every instant we can use the parallel axis theorem. (cont'd)

Comment: I think that the "orbital" and spinning" motions are simply an illusion due to the fact that the axis that passes through center of the mass of the system is not actually fixed in RF of the pad.

Comment: A quote from a your previous comment: "However as the number of involved objects increases there are more rotation axis allowed." I am a bit of sceptic about this. If you have say one million objects, are you going to work with million rotation axes?

Comment: @Martin. Very nice summary of our different view points. You definitly got my point, but obviously aren't yet convinced ;-). Let us assume that your assesment of the situation is correct. So the pad and the child are only rotating around the center of mass. In this case we can use the pictures in my answer to discuss the problem. I assume you agree on the position of the child and the position of the pad in the three depicted moments. Ok, lets now take a look at the baby at t=0 in the first situation. (continued)

Comment: At that very instant the baby is pushing himself upwards, in the direction of the upper end of your screen. Newton tells us Actio equals Reactio. Therefore there is a torque applied to the pad. This torque is directed downwards to the lower end of your screen. Therefore the pad should start to rotate clockwise. However as you can see in Situation t=t_1, the center of mass of the pad has gone counter clockwise. So we are in some kind of trouble now. (continued)

Comment: We simultaniously have a clockwise and a counter clockwise rotation. So lets analyse this situation. If we just look at the rotation around the center of mass of the system, we would neglect the influence of the counter clockwise rotation of the pad. So thats not good ^^. If we assume one rotation cancels a bit of the other rotation, we would end up with the center of mass of our system moving! Why??? Because the babys acceleration is independent of the canceling of the two rotations. The baby is simply pushing himself forward. What the pad is doing with the torque is irrelevant to the baby.

Comment: The only way to resolve this dilemma is to assume that there is an orbital and a spinning motion of the pad. The center of mass of the pad is rotating counter clockwise. The pad itself is spinning clockwise. This is why the splitting in an orbital and a spinning part is necessary.

Comment: In regard to my previous comment: If I had a million axes I would use statistical physics ;-) No seriously, it depends on the configuration of the system. If all the parts are statically linked, then I would not have to consider them. However If they are independent I would have to take care of them. By the way this is related to something you are doing in thermodynamics. In order to calcualte the average energy of molecules in an ideal gas, one has to count the degrees of freedoms of these molecules. Of course one is not counting them, but applying generall formulas.

Comment: However the basic ideas remains the same. We have to deal with these degrees of freedom.

Comment: @ftiaronsem  You do not understand me correctly probably. Your reasoning would be correct if i would have expected the center of mass of the system to be fixed relative the pad. No, the pad with child moves relative the center of mass of the system so that the pad rotates always clockwise about the the axis. By the way, can you explain in case of zero-mass pad why the pad rotates namely $\frac{4\pi}{3}$?

Comment: This limit is caused by the superposition of orbiting and spinning rotation of the system. The pad spins clockwise and the baby is moving counterclockwise. Therefore the pad does not have to to spin the full $2\pi$ but something less, since the babys movement is contributing the other part. This turns out to be $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. Why do you think that my argumentation in my previous comment fails if the pad and the child move relative to the center of mass? This is included in my reasoning since I based it on the pictures, which are including this type of motion.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Note that in case of zero-mass pad COM of the system and COM of the child coincide. Thus the child does not move relative the ground and the pad must rotate $2\pi$ if at all. But this coincides with the case where COM of the pad is fixed. Unfortunately, there is represented no coordinate system of the pad in your figure. It gives the impression that the pad rotates about a fixed axis. The pad move in such manner relative COM of the system that the last draws a full circle on the pad, centered at the origin of the pad(by my opinion).Your analysis does not take this into account.

Comment: @Martin. You are right, I wasn't clear before. By the baby moving counterclockwise, I ment the counter clockwise movement of the system pad+baby. In case of a zero mass pad, only the pad is orbiting and not the baby. But the result will be the same. So the pad does not have to rotate $2\pi$. However the second part of your answer surprises me a bit. You are perefectly correct that the COM of the system draws a circle on the pad (I have to consider whether it has to be a full circle). But it can only do so if the pad is spinning.

Comment: However this is something you considered wrong before, isn't it? You said there could only be one motion, orbiting or spinning. It is exactly that spinning and orbiting part Mark includes in his calculation. I think it would be very helpfull to continue this discussion via some sort of IM or VoIp or even Landline? Do you have something like a skype account or shall we meet in teamspeak?

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I have no skype or something similar. And my internet connection is very slow. But i'm glad that our views have approached somewhat. Let's begin with COM of the system. The pad can move relative the COM (so that the COM draws a circle on the pad) without any rotation relative the ground(in given case the radius of the circle is equal to the distance from the center of mass of the system). I checked this experimentally with a disk on a table. I think that this is your error point. You and Mark count this as an orbital motion but this motion contributes nothing to the angular...

Comment: ...momentum(this is a very important point, think well before you answer, i repeat:the pad can move without any rotation(translational motion)). Now during this motion, to satisfy conservation of angular momentum it is sufficient that the pad revolves around COM of the system. Your analysis of zero-mass pad is incorrect. The pad can not  rotate independently of child.

Comment: I would like to improve the error in the previous comment. While the pad is performing translational motion around COM of the system it contributes to the angular momentum of the system, of course. I just wanted to say that this motion contributes nothing to the angular displacement of the pad.

Comment: Ok, I think I better understand your point now. Let me summarize: We both agree that the pad is performing a translational motion around the COM. Furthermore we both agree, that the pad is also spinning around its geometrical center (I derive that from you saying that the COM is drawing a circle on the pad.). However you are convinced that the translational motion of the pad is having no influence on the angle the baby has to crawl. Is this so far correct?

Comment: @ftiaronsem: No, the pad is not spinning around its geometrical axis. Translational motion of a rigid body means that its angular velocity is zero. I again suggest you to experiment with a real disk on a plane. Believe me, this is very useful(at least for me). The pad can move relative the COM without any rotation(or angular displacement) relative the ground. It is very easy to explain why in case of zero-mass pad its angular displacement is zero. In this case the center of mass of the system coincides with center of mass of child. So child must remain stationary relative the ground and not...

Comment: ...rotate. Only way the pad can move in this case is to perform a translational motion underneath the child. In so doing, the COM draws a full circle (with radius equal to the radius of the pad) on the pad(or in other words: child makes the same full circle on the pad). This confirms correctness of your first solution(again, it is very informative to check this result with playing with a real disk on a plane).  90% of my arguments are based on this experimenting. At this point, what do you think, makes it sense to discuss further? It seems that we can not reach an agreement in the near future.

Comment: @Martin: I did these experiments with a disk on the table. And they are suitable for supporting both our points. Please try Mark's Solution with such a disk on a table. You will see that it also works beatifully. Your key missunderstanding is that you assume that the COM can draw a full circle on the pad, without a spinning motion of the pad. You neglect the fact, that the baby and the center of mass of the pad stay always opposite in regard to the COM. Look at my pictures. In this case the COM is always fixed to one point on the pad.

Comment: If you allow the COM to draw a full circle on the pad, than the pad has either to be spinning or the COM moving. Since the latter is not possible, the first has to be true. Please note that the baby and the center of mass of the pad are opposite for all times!!! Furthermore I want you to consider the following: If you would be right, Mark's solution would have shown that the pad is not spinning. He just gave the system onother degree of freedom. If you would be right, this additional parameter would turn out to be zero! But its not! Physics tells us that the pad is also spinning.

Comment: Moreover our view points seemed to have fit, before Mark showed me my mistake. Looking back, I really see that it was a mistake. Furthermore the up votes of my solution came only for the simple case with a fixed axis. For my generall solution I got in fact downvotes! Mark however got upvotes for his solution. There are really a bunch of competent people on this site. If they are giving this solution upvotes, it is highly likely to be correct. This reasoning helped me a lot in overcoming the mistake in my considerations.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I see you're ready to continue the discussion. OK, i myself would be interesting to find out where it leads. I shall consider only one of your misconceptions at this time.  Quote: *"Your key missunderstanding is that you assume that the COM can draw a full circle on the pad, without a spinning motion of the pad. You neglect the fact, that the baby and the center of mass of the pad stay always opposite in regard to the COM."*  This statement is simply wrong! The distance from the center of pad to the COM is $d$. The pad with child can move relative the COM without spinning and(or)

Comment: ...orbiting so that $d=const$ and that means that the COM draws a circle with radius $d$ on the pad. In such motion the requirement that the baby and the center of mass of the pad stay always opposite in regard to the COM is is automatically satisfied. This is also an experimental fact! With regard to the fact that Mark's answer is highly upvoted then i agree that in general this is a good indicator. But this is a quantitative problem and not a trivial one. None is supported Mark's answer quantitatively, with rational arguments. I think that most of the upvotes are due to the nice video and...

Comment: ...figures and Mark's reputation score. But a high reputation score or an impressive video  does not lead automatically to a correct answer.

Comment: @Martin: I am very glad that you also agree on continuing this discussion. Unfortunatelly I can't follow you saying "The pad with child can move relative the COM without spinning and(or) orbiting so that d=const and that means that the COM draws a circle with radius d on the pad" If the center of mass is fixed and if there is no spinning and no orbiting rotation, how can the center of mass than draw a circle on the pad? In regard to Mark's calculations: Do you have an explanation why the additional angle Mark introduced is greater than zero, in case your assesment of the physics is correct?

Comment: @ftiaronsem: There was a mistake in my saying, of course. The pad performs also an orbital motion. For me this splitting is only a confusing thing:) What do you mean by additional angle?  I read over Mark's solution and want to draw attention to a fundamental mistake in his first equation: $Md^2\dot{\theta} + m(R-d)^2\dot{\theta} + \frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\phi} = 0; \theta = \alpha + \phi.$ Here $\theta$ is the translational angular displacement of the pad, $\phi$ is the whole angular displacement of the pad and $\alpha$ is the angular displacement of child relative the pad.The equation does not...

Comment: ...take into account the angular momentum due to the motion of child relative the pad. For ex. if $\theta=0$ then the angular momentum is $\frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\phi}=-\frac{MR^2}{2}\dot{\alpha}$ It does not contain mass of the child. Please explain.

Comment: @Marting Well $\phi$ is not the total displacement of the pad, but the displacement caused by the pad spinning. Therefore Mark's allowed to write $\theta - \phi = 2 \pi$ near the end of his explanation. Note the minus sign here is correct because $\phi$ is negative. And the equation is taking the angular momentum of the child's movement in account. Thats what $m(R-d)^2\dot{\theta}$ is for. Please note that one isn't allowed to set $\theta$ and $\phi$ to arbitrary values. This is closely related to why I said Mark introduced an additional variable.

Comment: Mark is using the variable $\theta$ to describe the pads orbiting motion and he is using the variable $\phi$ to describe the pads spinning motion. If your assesment of the situation would be correct, than one should get $\phi =0$ at the end of the calculation. But one is not, physics tell us otherwise. I think it is very usefull to discuss Mark's ansatz and you doubts about it. This is something solid (based on mathematics) to discuss about.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: It is clear now where we go separate ways, i think. We agree that the pad performs translational motion relative the COM. Or orbital motion by you and Mark. These are the same. Such motion does not contribute to the angular displacement of the pad.  But you and Mark think that the whole angular displacement of the pad is due to the spinning around its center of mass and i think that this displacement is due to the rotating around the COM. If I understand things right now then you are profoundly incorrect. The whole point of this problem is that the pad and child rotate around...

Comment: ...the COM(the center of mass of the whole system). You have replaced rotating of the pad around the COM with rotating of the pad around its center of mass! I do not agree!

Comment: @Martin: Please look at my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

ftiaronsem is right, i think!

The law of conservation of angular momentum for this system must be expressed as $I_m\omega_m+I_M\omega_M=0$ where $I_m$ and $I_M$ are the moments of inertia of the child and the pad about the axis which passes through the center of the mass of the whole system and $\omega_m$ and $\omega_M$ are corresponding angular velocities in the reference frame of the ground (or stationary water). More specifically, $\omega_M$ is angular velocity of the center of the pad.

**Mark Eichenlaub** argues that this is not sufficient and we need to include yet the angular momentum of the pad's translation as well as the angular momentum of the pad's spinning. I think this is a fundamental mistake. This is best explained by analogs in rotational and linear motion, i think.

Let's consider the case where the child moves along a diameter of the pad. This is a linear motion and the law of conservation of linear momentum for this system must be expressed as $mv_m+Mv_M=0$ where $m$ an $M$ are masses of the child and the pad and $v_m$ and $v_M$ are corresponding velocities in the reference frame of the ground (or stationary water). Let's  gather  the results together:

$$mv_m+Mv_M=0$$  $$I_m\omega_m+I_M\omega_M=0$$  Moments of inertia $I_m,I_M$  and angular velocities $\omega_m,\omega_M$ are the rotational analogs of $m,M$ and $v_m,v_M$ and corresponding equations  must look like the same way.

ftiaronsem's final formula

$$\theta = \frac{m\left(1 - \frac{m}{m+M}\right)^22\pi}{\left(\frac{M}{2} + M\left(\frac{m}{m+M}\right)^2 + m\left(1 - \frac{m}{m+M}\right)^2\right)}$$

can be simplified. For purposes of brevity let's introduce the ratio $x=\frac{m}{M}$. Then finally the angular displacement of the pad: 
$$\theta=\frac{2x}{(1+x)(1+3x)}2\pi$$  An amazing thing of this result is that the angular displacement of the pad has a maximum absolute value. It reaches the maximum displacement at $x=\frac{m}{M}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ where the maximum is:
$$\theta_{max}=(2-\sqrt{3})2\pi=96.5^\circ$$ Another surprise is that **if the child is infinitely heavy then the pad's rotation is zero!**

Comment: That's just not how it works.  Please read these two pages from a standard textbook. http://goo.gl/NvMeX  Specifically, quoted from the bottom of page two, "consider the motion of a planet around the sun... In this case... the total angular momentum of the planet is the angular momentum of the orbital motion of the CM around the sun, plus the angular momentum of its spinning motion around its CM."

Comment: To be more specific, you can't always write $L = I\omega$.  You can write $L = r\times p$.  Only in special simple cases can that be simplified too $L = I\omega$.

Comment: @Mark:The orbital motion case is not a good comparison. The planet's spin is independent of its orbital motion and the rule: "the angular momentum of the orbital motion of the CM around the sun, plus the angular momentum of its spinning motion around its CM" applies. However in given case the pad's spin is not independent of its "orbital" motion and you can not apply this rule like you did. The formula $L = I\omega$ applies in this case because $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\omega}$ are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Also Mark, consider the specific case where the mass of the pad is zero(or child is infinitely heavy). Then the pad contributes nothing to the angular momentum of the system, rotates it or not. So there is no reason that it would start spinning at all.

Comment: And third, Mark. In the case of zero mass of the pad your solution assumes that the pad turns around the child the angle $2\pi$. This is impossible without sliding between the pad and the child. But sliding friction is different from zero. So the rotation of the pad around the child is impossible.

Comment: @Martin Did you actually read the link I gave you?  The result about "orbital" and "spin" momentum is completely general.  It is always applicable.  The formula $L = I\omega$ applies when the velocities everywhere can be described by $v = \omega \times r$.  Here, they can't.

Comment: @Martin Do not trust your intuition in the zero-mass pad limit.  If the pad has no angular moment, the baby can still turn because it's a point mass, and a point spinning in space contributes no angular momentum, either.  Your statement about sliding between the pad and child is nonsensense.  Put your finger on a piece of paper and it can twirl around underneath your finger easily.  No friction is involved because the baby is a point mass, so there is no relative motion between the baby and the part of the pad directly underneath.

Comment: Here, try this exercise.  I think it will help.  Imagine that the pad is going to rotate around a fixed axis through the center of mass of the system, as if someone stuck a pole through that point and the pad is spinning around it.  Try calculating the angular momentum about that pole in two ways - one by using the parallel axis theorem, and again by calculating the "orbital" and "spin" angular momenta separately.  You get the same answer, showing that my method is general.  Unfortunately, you can't solve the problem with this figure; it applies to a different sort of motion than what occurs.

Comment: @Mark: The exercise shows exactly where is your fundamental mistake. The angular velocity of the rotation of the pad is **always** the same  for both "orbital and "spin" motions. I've kept this in mind when i said that the pad's "spin" is not independent of its "orbital" motion. However in your first equation "spin" and "orbital" have different angular velocities ($\dot{\phi}$ and $\dot{\theta}$). This is fundamentally incorrect! The angular velocity of the rigid body has "absolute" property. So parallel axis theorem applies in this problem.

Comment: @Mark: There is nothing to do with my intuition. In the zero-mass pad limit the center of mass of the point mass is at the same time the center of mass of the system. You can only turn the body which owns the spatial dimensions. What forces will turn the point mass in this problem?

Comment: @martin Why do you think the angular velocity is the same for "orbital" and "spin" motions?  We should not simply assume that.  Instead, we allow them to be anything, and then after applying physical constraints find their true form.

Comment: In fact, it is easy to see that one cannot conserve angular momentum if the pad moves in a pure rotational motion around the center of mass of the system.  The child and center of pad must rotate around the system center of mass in the same direction because they must stay opposite each other.  Hence, in this case their angular momenta point the same way.  Two vectors that point in the same direction won't add up to zero.

Comment: As for the zero-mass pad, I suggest thinking about it as a limit.  You cannot say $\lim_{x\to 0}sin(x)/x = 0$ because the numerator is zero, and you can't say it's infinite because the denominator is zero.  You have to consider them both and think about the limit.  To answer your specific question,  it doesn't take any force at all to spin a point mass, so none is required.

Comment: Mark: This is a property of the motion of a rigid body. The angular velocity of a rigid body $\vec{\omega}$ is uniquely determined and is independent of the particular coordinate system chosen (in given case the coordinate system associated with the center of mass of the pad and the coordinate system associated with the center of mass of the pad + child). I read about this from Landau & Lifshitz "Mechanics".

Comment: @Mark: I really like the zero-mass pad. Suppose that the child is almost a point mass (i.e. have an infinitesimally small  inertial moment, different from zero). Because the angular momentum of the whole system is initially exactly zero then the rotation of the child is impossible. Now consider a limit process. In this process the inertial moment can never be equal to zero. Thus the child never rotate.

Comment: @Martin Please look up eq. 31.2 and 31.3 of Landau and Lifschitz (referencing 3rd ed.), which make it clear that when calculating the velocity of parts of the rigid body, we need to account for both the motion of its center of mass and its rotation.  When L&L discuss angular momentum, they state, "The value of the angular momentum of a system depends, as we know, on the point with respect to which it is defined.  In the mechanics of a rigid body, the most appropriate point to choose for this purpose is the origin of the moving system of co-ordinates, i.e. centre of mass of the body..."

Comment: Since in this particular problem I decided it was easiest to calculate the angular momentum relative to a different axis than the center of mass of the pad, my expression for the angular momentum has another term which Landau and Lifschitz do not show because they did not calculate the angular momentum in this way.

Comment: @Martin I agree that the angular velocity of the pad's rotation is uniquely defined.  I disagree that we can apply that angular velocity to describe the bulk motion of the entire pad in space.  What L&L are saying is that no matter how the pad moves as a whole, its rotation about its center of mass is the same in any frame.  That doesn't mean we can ignore the bulk motion of the pad, or that if the entire pad is moving in a circle around some point, the angular velocity of that bulk motion is the same as the angular velocity of spinning.  That's a misinterpretation of L&L by a long shot.

Comment: @Martin regarding the zero-mass pad.  The rotation of the child is immaterial; the real point is the rotation of the pad.  (The child is actually moving in a smaller and smaller circle as it gets heavier.)  I find it difficult to build good intuition for what the zero-mass pad does.  I will trust the answer I get from doing physics and prefer to discuss the physical arguments that lead up to finding the rotation of the pad for any masses.

Comment: @Mark: Our answers match when the pad is infinitely heavy and are completely different when the pad's mass is zero. In the last case we must decide which is the correct answer. In my last comment i gave a strong and simple answer based on the law of the conservation of angular momentum: The pad will never rotate. I still do not see your proof that the pad rotates $4\pi$ in this case.

Comment: @Martin I found an error in my answer.  I think the pad rotates $4\pi/3$ in the limit $m>>M$.  My proof is that as long as my equations are correct, this is the answer they give.  Again, intuition easily fails here.  If the pad has no mass, it can have any rotation at all without violating angular momentum conservation.  Did you read the section I quoted from L&L?  Are we making any progress in reconciling on my use of angular momentum?  I do not want to discuss the limiting case further.  I am not obligated to describe it especially; correctly analyzing the general case is sufficient.

Comment: @Mark: Problems are not solved by ignoring them (zero-mass pad).The pad can not have any rotation because in this case it must slide relative the child. But  this is impossible due to friction forces. But Mark, remember the excercise you gave. There you considered the case where the center of the mass of the whole system is fixed. And you assumed there that angular velocities of "spin" and "orbit" are the same. And allowed to use the parallel axis theorem. But there is no difference is the center of mass of the system actually fixed or not! It does not move under any circumstances.

Comment: @Mark: From L&L i use the following quote:  "We see that the angular velocity of rotation, at any instant, of a system of co-ordinates fixed in the body is independent of the particular system chosen. All such systems rotate with angular velocities $\vec{\omega}$ which are equal in magnitude and parallel in direction. This enables us to call $\vec{\omega}$ the angular velocity of the body." (page 97)

Comment: @Martin The quote from L&L doesn't support your claim.  It is only talking about the angular momentum of spinning.  There is no orbital angular momentum accounted for.  They only consider angular momentum about the center of mass.  You appear to be making the claim that it is impossible, in principle, for the pad to circle around a point with one angular velocity and to spin on its own axis with a different one. If I'm interpreting you correctly, you think that you can't ever have two pads circling at the same rate, but one spinning fast and the other spinning slowly, regardless of the forces.

Comment: @martin As for sliding and friction, I have no idea what you mean.  TOf course the baby can move relative to the pad.  It does it by crawling.  I really have no idea what you mean here with the sliding stuff.  Maybe you are talking about the pad spinning underneath the baby?  That doesn't cause any sliding or relative motion because the baby is a point mass.  I'm not ignoring the problem of a zero-mass pad.  I'm solving it by solving the general case, then examining the limit.  That's a legitimate solution method.

Comment: @Mark: Yes,i think that you can't ever have two pads circling at the same rate, but one spinning fast and the other spinning slowly, if they circle around an axis which passes through the pad! In given case around the axis which passes through the center of mass of the system. Yes, i am talking about the pad spinning underneath the baby. Note that the baby is not  defined at zero inertial moment. Its inertial moment can be made as close as desired to $0$ by making its dimensions close enough, but not equal, to $0$. Thus the sliding friction is fact!

Comment: @Mark: I think that the L&L quote support my claim though. Note that the pad circles around the axis which passes through the pad. The coordinate system associated with this axis is fixed in the pad.

Comment: @Mark: Try experimenting with a real disk on a table. You will see that if the disk rotates about an axis which passes through the disk then the angular displacement of a circling radius is equal to the angular displacement of a spinning radius.

Comment: @Martin Your statements are correct assuming that the disk rotates about an axis through itself, but that is not the motion of the disk.  Why are you assuming it must move that way?  I made a video illustrating the motion (the sound got a little messed up, but it should still get the idea across) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqCjbo-Ua2M

Comment: @Mark:+1 for the good Hollywood physics video(Do not take it too seriously:). Unfortunately, i can not up vote your incorrect answer so i'll keep that +1 for future:). Mark, seriously, the only thing that counts is the rotation of the pad about the axis that passes through the center of mass of the system. There is no need to introduce an orbital and spinning motions. This just makes things confusing. There is only one unique rotation with unique angular velocity about the axis.

Comment: @Martin Did the video's first animation at least give an accurate description of the motion that you think occurs, before presenting the alternative that I think occurs?  When I showed an animation saying I was sticking a pencil through the center of mass, did that part show the motion that you advocate?  I want to make sure I understand what it is you think happens.

Comment: @Mark: To be honest i can not imagine how the pad actually moves. Geometry is one of my weakest point. My perception is based solely on the analytical solution which I believe to be true. I think it is time to stop now. It seems that we are unable to reach agreement on this issue as if both. But in any case, i learned a lot from you. Thanks for discussion!

Comment: @Martin In that case, you should not "accept" ftiaronsem's solution.  It's incorrect; even ftiaronsem understands this, although he/she doesn't have enough experience to work out the full solution.  By accepting the  incorrect solution, you're giving the Physics.SE stamp of approval to the wrong answer.  (The solution's upvotes almost all came when ftiaronsem solved the much more limited problem where the pad cannot translate at all.)

Comment: @Mark: It is not proved that ftiaronsems's solution is incorrect. I accepted he's/she's answer because i accepted its derivation and final result. My saying "To be honest i can not imagine how the pad actually moves." does not mean that i doubt about the correctness of the ftiaronsems's solution. My question was about an angular displacement of the pad not about its trajectory. I see no reason to continue the discussion because you do not care about the arguments based on the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: @Martin What kind of insane rambling is that?  I based my entire argument on conservation of momentum and I showed in detail why ftiarsonem's solution is wrong.  When I provided links to a book which showed that my approach is correct, you dismissed it offhand with a nonsense argument.  When you provided your own reference, I read it and explained carefully why it does not support the view you've adopted.  You had the opportunity to learn something here, but you wasted it by covering your ears and screaming "I can't hear you" louder and louder.

Comment: @Mark: Also, i see no problem with this issue actually because Physics.SE accepted your perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @Mark: I showed twice that your solution fails in case of zero-mass pad. This proof is based strongly on the conservation of angular momentum. I think i do not have to do this a third time.

Comment: @martin Although my answer is correct, I still need to apologize for calling your post "insane rambling".  I felt very frustrated that, as best I could tell, you did not understand my argument.  Maybe you did understand it and still objected, but that wasn't how I saw it and I think I did not exercise enough restraint.

Comment: @Mark. Your last comment was noble, good one.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in two steps:

1. Prove that the lily will only spin and not translate
2. Find the spinning velocity and therefore the angle

**The lily only rotates**

This can be resolved geometrically. The baby must turn right to keep their circular trajectory, with respect to the lily. It will therefore exert a force on the lily equal and opposite to their centripetal force (i.e. the force they use to turn right).

The force exerted by the baby is of constant magnitude and direction towards the center of the lily. The reaction force is also of constant magnitude but with direction outside the lily.

What is the net effect of force on the baby as time passes? We can obtain it be subtracting the centripetal forces at small intervals of time. Geometry and common sense show that the net effect is a vector tangential to the trajectory of the baby (obviously).

Now we can think about the net effect of the force on the lily. The force is exactly the same magnitude as the one on the baby, but with opposite direction. We can also see it as the same direction and negative magnitude. So the forces will compose over time in the same way as the baby, but with the opposite sign. So in other words the net effect is that the lily spins backwards.

As there are no other forces acting on the system, the lily will only spin on its axis.

**Calculating the angle**

Let $\theta$ be the angle of rotation of the baby, and $\phi$ the angle of rotation of the lily. Let the ratio of the masses, $\frac{M}{m}=\mu$

Since the baby always keeps the same distance from the center of the lily, both $\ddot\theta=0=\ddot\phi$ and therefore

$$\dot\theta = \omega_{b}$$
and
$$\dot\phi = \omega_{l}$$

Both are constants.

In the frame of reference of the pond, the lily will rotate with angular velocity $\omega_l$ and the baby will rotate with angular velocity $\omega_b+\omega_l$.

Angular momentum must be conserved, so:

$$(\omega_b+\omega_l) m r^2 = -I\omega_{l} $$

Substituting $I=\frac{Mr^2}{2}$ and solving for $\omega_l$ gives

$$\omega_l = -\omega_b\frac{2}{\mu+2}$$

Now, the time that is necessary for a full rotation of the baby is $t_{f}=2\pi/\omega_b$. The angle $\phi$ rotated by the lily is therefore equal to

$$\phi=\omega_l t_f=-\frac{4\pi}{\mu+2}$$

Comment: @sklivvz When you say "the lily will only spin on its axis" what axis are you referring to?  Is that an axis through the geometrical center of the lily pad?

Comment: @Mark Yes, all the forces are centripetal (or centrifugal), so the net effect is that.

Comment: @Sklivvz So you think the following two statements are true: 1) The lily pad alone, not considering the child, experiences a net force.  2)The center of mass of the lily pad does not accelerate.  Is that right?

Comment: @Mark if you have something to say, then say it... :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Okay.  If the lily pad's center stays in one spot and the baby moves, then the center of mass of the system moves.  By conservation of linear momentum, the center of mass of the system cannot move.  Therefore, your answer is incorrect.  From the point of view of forces, if there is any net force on the lily pad, its center must accelerate.

Comment: @Sklivvz see the nice graphic by ftiaronsem in his answer.  It's a very clear visualization.

Comment: @Mark except that there are forces at play, because the baby is always steering right to keep the circular trajectory. The linear momentum of the lily is conserved if the lily not translating. The baby is exerting a force and does not conserve it.

Comment: @Mark otherwise all spinning systems would violate conservation of linear momentum?

Comment: @Sklivvz I do not understand what systems you are considering in your reply.  The linear momentum that is conserved is the momentum of the entire system = the baby and the lily considered jointly.  Thus, it is the center of mass of that system that is stationary.  The lily itself does not conserve its momentum separately from the baby because there is an external force on it (from the baby).

Comment: @Sklivvz spinning does not create any net linear momentum

Comment: @Mark: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_throw (let's move to chat)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Your answer coincides with ftiaronsem's first solution where the geometrical axis of the lily is fixed. Conflict! :-)

Comment: Yes, I am rethinking the first bit

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just for the purpose of discussion. It will be edited sometimes and It may contain wrong conclusions.

@Martin: I am trying to image the motion you are describing. Unfortunatelly I have some severe difficulties, since I always run into some kind of contradiction. Therefore I have drawn two motions, in which the pad is not rotating. Please tell me which one you think is appropriate for this problem.

Motion one:
[image: Assuming counterclockwise baby motion]

Motion two: 
[image: Assuming counterclockwise baby motion]

Sorry for one time drawing a clockwise and one time drawing a counterclockwise baby-motion. As I noticed, it was already too late to change. But this should make no difference for the sake of argument.

Please also tell, if you think of a different motion of the pad and try describing / or drawing it.

Thanks

ftiaronsem

Comment: @ftiaronsem, Yes motion two is the motion what I am keeping in an eye.

Comment: @Martin. Hmm, but you notice that the center of the pad and the child are always opposite to the COM. They do not change their relative positions. So with this motion the baby is never leaving his initial position on the pad.

Comment: @ftiaronsem, but you said that the pad does not rotate(relative the coordinate system in the figure). In this case the angular displacement of child relative the pad is the same as the angular displacement of the center of the pad relative the COM and the center of the pad and the child are always opposite to the COM. Note that the angular displacement of the center of the pad relative the COM does not count as an angular displacement of the pad relative the coordinate system (which is still zero).

Comment: @Martin. Im am very sorry but I again have difficulties in following your resoning. You say _In this case the angular displacement of child relative the pad is the same as the angular displacement of the center of the pad relative the COM_. I have difficulties understanding the last part: _angular displacement of the center of the pad relative the COM_ There can be no angular displacement between two points. Which lines in my figure have you ment?

Comment: @ftiaronsem Look at the right figure. The straight line between center of pad and child coincides with the horizontal axis. Now, look at the figure which is in the middle. The line have turned counterclockwise by an angle. You said that the pad does not rotate.(that is a translational motion) The only way how the child can get to the position on this figure is to rim by the angle relative the pad.

Comment: @Martin. You are perfectly correct by saying that the baby has to rim exactly this angle. However you are overlooking something. Please consider the following: In picture number one, the starting point of the baby is on the intersection of the rim of the pad and the line between the COM and the center of the pad. Taking a look at the following pictures, the baby is always remaining on exactly that intersection. So if there is no spinning motion of the pad (which we assume here), the displacement between the childs starting position and the childs current position is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just for the purpose of discussion. It will be edited sometimes and It may contain wrong conclusions.

@Martin. I wanted to add another argument that one has a spinning motion as well as an orbital motion. In order to keep the arguments seperated, I choose a new answer. Please consider the following

If one has a force acting **anywhere** on a rigid body, this force is causing an acceleration of the center of mass of the body (described by $F=ma$) and it is simultaneously causing an angular acceleration of the body (described by $M=r\times F$).

So in case of our baby, the force acted upon the pad causes the center of mass of the pad to translate and causes the pad to spin. Using the above principle it should be pretty obvious that both a spinning (around the center of mass of the pad) and a translational motion (an orbital one in our case) of the pad take place.

In order to further clarify the intended motion I have drawn new pictures, illustrating the situation. The red line is marking the starting position of the baby. The curved arrow is indicating the angular velocity of the pad (counterclockwise). In these pictures, the baby itself is always moving clockwise.

[image]
[image]

In these pictures, one can see an orbital motion of the center of the pad around the center of masss of the system (COM). This motion is caused by $F=ma$. Furthermore one can see a spinning motion of the pad around the center of the pad, which is caused by $M=r\times F$. As one can see in these pictures, both angular motions contribute to the displacement between the childs current and its original position.

@Mark. If you are still following this question, feel free to include or modify any of my pictures in your answer.

Comment: @ftiaronsem. Ok, let's consider only a spinning motion. But in this case the pad does not rotate around the center of mass of the system(the COM). The center of the pad is stationary relative the COM. Only rotation around the COM contributes to the angular momentum of the whole system. You can not add the spinning momentum to the angular momentum of the whole system.

Comment: @Martin. One isn't allowed to consider only one motion. A fundamental principle of classical mechanics states that every force on a rigid body, is causing both motions (translational and rotational) to happen at the same time (described by the equations above). In my new pictures you can then observe how these two motions sum up to the total displacement of the child relative to its starting position.

Comment: @ftiaronsem. Your last response is an excellent one. This make things much more clear also to me. Quote: "*In these pictures, one can see an orbital motion of the center of the pad around the center of masss of the system (COM). This motion is caused by **F=ma**"*. **Thus this motion contributes to the linear momentum not to the angular momentum**. I was also incorrect when i thought that this translational motion contributes to the angular momentum. I would have understood it earlier: translational motion contributes only to the linear momentum. You have shown yourself (inadvertently) that...

Comment: ...your solution is incorrect.

Comment: Ahh, great, this discussion is really making progress. I will start with a quote from wikipedia concerning angular momentum: _The angular momentum L of a particle about a given origin is defined as: $M = r \times p$ where $r$ is the position vector of the particle relative to the origin, $p$ is the linear momentum of the particle_ There are several important things here to notice. First angular momentum is always defined, no matter whether we have a real rotation or simply a linear motion. One can define an angular momentum for every given point in space.

Comment: Of course there is only one sensible point in space to calculate the angular momentum in our case: The COM. Why? Because every other point (on the pad, or the child), would be in an accelerated reference frame, therefore suffering from fictious forces. The second important point to notice is that $p$ is the linear momentum! And this momentum is caused by $F=ma$! We all know that linear momentum is defined by $F=\dot{p}$. So for any given moment in time $p=mv$. Furthermore for any given moment in time $v$ can be written as $v=r\dot{\theta} \Rightarrow p=mr\dot{\theta}$

Comment: Now put this in the definition of angular momentum. In our case  the velocity is always vertical to the radius, therefore the cross product simplifies to $M = rp = mr^2\dot{\theta}$. As I said before, the only reasonable point to calculate the angular momentum is the COM. So $r=d \Rightarrow M=md^2\dot{\theta}$. In our case the mass of the pad is $M$. So one finally gets $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ (Sorry for double using $M$) for the angular momentum, which is exactly what Mark is using in his answer.

Comment: The crucial point about all this stuff is, that angular momentum is always defined, no matter what motion. Therefore you can always apply the conservation of angular momentum. However many problems without a rotational symmetry are difficult to solve with angular momentum, due to the cross product. This is why everyone is using linear momentum for linear motions ;-)

Comment: @ftiaronsem. Your arguments are very impressive ;-) But you missed a fundamental point. Together with angular momentum of the system(AMS) must be conserved also the linear momentum of the system(LMS). The translational motion of the pad is due to the requirement that LMS must be conserved. So you simply added up AMS and LMS and got AMS. This is an illegal operation ;-)

Comment: @Martin. _So you simply added up AMS and LMS and got AMS._ Well that would be illegal, however we are not adding AMS and LMS! At least not directly. As I argued before, every Linear Momentum (LM) can be expressed as an angular Momentum (AM) to a given point. So we are transforming the LM to an AM and add afterwards. Thats legal ;-).

Comment: @ftiaronsem. Consider at this time only translational motion of the pad. Do I understand correctly that you "transform" this motion into an angular motion and add it to the angular momentum equation? My point of view is that this motion contributes nothing to the angular momentum because the pad does not rotate about the COM in this motion.

Comment: @Martin. _Do I understand correctly that you "transform" this motion into an angular motion and add it to the angular momentum equation?_ Yeah, I think this is what one could call it. However there are some subtile points that we have to consider in order to write down the equation Mark uses in his answer. I will stress them in the following lines. One important thing you are pointing out correctly is the difficulty of applying the conservation of momentum in a case where we have translational as well as rotational motion.

Comment: If we would just use conservation of linear momentum we would neglect the _rotational_ angular momentum, and vice versa. So what equations shall we use? Luckily physics is rescuing us here since angular momentum and all its conclusions are defined for any given trajectory and any point in space (see my last comments and wikipedia). So by applying the formula for angular momentum we are allowed to treat the rotational and linear parts of motion in just one equation. Thus enabling us to express the conservation of momentum of the whole system.

Comment: The second important part is to consider that in our recent discussion we have always looked at some specific moment in time. But what is happening as time goes on? If the baby has moved a tiny little bit it has to change its direction in order to stay on the rim of the flower (Otherwise it would take a bath ^^). Therefore the linear acceleration also changes its direction. This change of linear accel. is happening constantly while the baby is making his way on the rim. This acceleration is always tangental to the pad. Therefore the translational motion of the pad starts to forms a circle.

Comment: Hence the Ansatz of Mark proves to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Hmm, but wait. I left something out ;-) You could indeed argue that I was a bit fast on reasoning that _the translational motion of the pad starts to forms a circle._ One could say that if there is no centrifugal force the pad would move in a curved trajectory. Where is the centrifugal force coming from that forces the pad on a circular movement? It is coming from the baby! The baby would like to do the same curved trajectory on its side of the COM. But since the Baby always stays on the pad, the pad and the baby force each other on a circular movement.

Comment: This indeed is a beautiful problem. Thank you very much for asking it here ;-)

Comment: @ftiaronsem. I do not agree that if we would just use conservation of linear momentum we would neglect the rotational angular momentum, and vice versa. In a closed system they both must be conserved at the same time. We can not ignore one looking at the second. This is a fundamental law! We observe all motions in the reference frame of COM. There is only two body in this closed system. The pad performs the translational motion relative the COM. There is no room to transform this motion to a circular one. I'll be back on Monday only. You'll have time to think over it deeply ;-)

Comment: P.S. You have not yet been satisfactorily explained zero-mass pad case.

Comment: @Martin. Well of course one could describe the entire system by just using linear momentum. However all the rotating parts of the system (in particular the spinning of the plant), are way more difficult to describe in terms of linear momentum (One would have to integrate over all mass elements) This is as valid as describing the system with angular momentum. However it would be way more complicated. So why should one do that? By saying that we would neglect either one of them, I had in mind that one would just look at the translational motion of the pad,

Comment: which would neglect the spinning of the plant and vice versa. Sorry that this was confusing. _There is no room to transform this motion to a circular one._ If the motion of the center of mass of the pad would not be circular the baby would simply fall of the pad (keep in mind that the center of mass has to be constant). Of course this is not an explanation why this circular motion is happening. But for a chain of reasoning see my comment from 22. Feb.

Comment: As for the zero mass pad, I already gave an explanation some weeks ago. It based basically on the pads orbital motion contributing to the angular displacement (See the pictures in this answer for illustration).

Comment: sorry for this additional comment, this one can be ignored, my mistake

Comment: @ftiaronsem. Ok, consider again only the translational motion of the pad. I will try to show why $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ is incorrect in the angular momentum equation, in my opinion. Let $\theta$ be infinitesimally small. Then the pad shifts as a whole relative the COM by $d*\theta$. Now, $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ would be correct if the COM were outside the pad. Then all particles of the pad shift clockwise(counterclockwise) about the COM. However, if the COM is located within the pad then a part of particles of the pad shifts in the contrary to the remaining part about the COM.

Comment: @Martin. I am very sorry, but again I can not follow you on this point. Your reasoning would be correct if there would be a pole stuck through the pad (right at the COM). However this is not the case. As I hopefully showed you in this answer, the pad can float freely on the water. Therefore all particles on the pad shift (counter)clockwise about the COM. Spinning and orbital motion are independet in this problem (The only connection between both is the baby causing them)

Comment: @ftiaronsem. We pay our attention only to the translational(or orbital by you) motion of the pad and want to calculate its angular moment about the COM in this motion. Everything else you mentioned is irrelevant. All particles of the pad move in one direction in this motion. I will not continue at present because i want to know are you agree with this little.

Comment: Damn! I have expressed myself incorrectly. If we consider the translational motion of the pad without the child, then of course it contributes $Md^2\dot{\theta}$ to the angular momentum. However, the child performs also translational motion with the pad, but contrary to the pad, about the COM. So corresponding two angular momentums will be mutually obliterated and the translational part of the movement of the system contributes nothing to the angular momentum of the system.

Comment: @Martin, I believe our viewpoints came very close recently. However the motions you describe are not yet correct. Since the COM remains fixed, the pad and the child translate in opposite directions on the _opposite_ side of the pad. Therefore they are rotating in the same direction and the angular momenta do not cancel. Please see the pictures in this answer for illustration.

Comment: @ftiaronsem Do not trust too much the pictures. They are too subjective.  I do not tire of repeating: we consider only translational motion. You must add the translational movement of the pad to the movement of the child(at the moment you are simply ignoring this). The child itself performs only rotational motion about the COM. The total movement of the child relative the COM is the sum of these movements. By the way, the problem is the easiest to solve in the reference frame of the COM. Can you do it in that way? In this case it is unnecessary to consider the translational motion.

Comment: @Martin _I do not tire of repeating: we consider only translational motion._ Yes we do, I was never talking about anything else. _By the way, the problem is the easiest to solve in the reference frame of the COM. Can you do it in that way? In this case it is unnecessary to consider the translational motion._ Isn't that we were doing in all the comments in this answer? I always argued from a fixed reference frame (in respect to the water) with its orign in the COM. Your last comment confused me quite a bit. In the following comment I try to clarfiy what we agree do not agree on.

Comment: @Martin Please tell which of the following points you agree / do not agree on. All the following points are described from an inertial reference frame, with the COM as its origin. This reference frame remains fixed relative to the surrounding water. ------ 1) The baby performs a rotational motion around the COM. (orbiting like a planet) ------ 2) The center of mass of the pad (COM-P) performs a rotational motion around the COM. (orbiting like a planet) ------ 3) The rotational motion of the COM-P has the same angular velocity as the the rotational motion of the child.

Comment: @Martin ------ 4) The pad is rotating around the COM-P (spinning like a spinning top) ------ These four points form the basis of Mark's answer. Please say what you do not agree on and why. Please be as precise as possible in case of doubts. Thanks.

Comment: @ftiaronsem  Actually, we consider the motion of the system in the RF of the ground(or water) not in the RF of the COM. These are different. Note that the COM can freely move relative the ground. But in given case the pad and child constitute a closed system and the velocity of the COM must remain constant(conservation of linear momentum). In given case the velocity is zero and this can create an illusion that we are looking at the movement of the system in the RF of the COM. If we consider the motion of the system in the RF of the COM then we can ignore movements due to the requirement...

Comment: ..that the COM must be stationary.  
1) agree, 2) agree, but in the RF of the COM it is unnecessary to consider this motion(this is a translational motion), 3) agree, 4) not agree! In this motion the rotations of the pad and child around the COM are zero. Remember, only the rotation around the COM contributes to the angular momentum of the system.

Comment: @Martin: You are confusing me again ;-). You tell me in 2 _agree, but in the RF of the COM it is unnecessary to consider this motion(this is a translational motion)_ and say in 4 _In this motion the rotations of the pad and child around the COM are zero. Remember, only the rotation around the COM contributes to the angular momentum of the system_ This is kind of a contradiction. This is one thing. But lets take a closer look at your reasoning of point 2): You tell me that it is unnecessary to consider this motion (since it is translational).

Comment: At the beginning of this comment series I showed you in great detail, that every motion (linear or rotational) contributes to the angular momentum of a system. A week ago, I showed you that the angular momentum caused by the babys motion and the angular momentum due to the movement of the COM-P do not cancel, but sum up. Therefore on definitly has to consider this motion. As for point 4, that is definitly not true. A simple example is a spinning top. It obviously has an angular momentum. Now Image this spinning top being an a piece of paper (Not on the middle of the paper)

Comment: Now slowly rotate the piece of paper. I think it is obvious that now 1) The angular momentum of the spinning top spinning 2) The angular momentum of the spinning top orbiting and 3) the angualar momentum of the paper rotating sum up to the total angular momentum. It is virtually the same in our case.

Comment: Just to be on the same boat here. You said _Actually, we consider the motion of the system in the RF of the ground(or water) not in the RF of the COM. These are different._ I agree. However as you also correctly state neither reference frame is is moving. No rotation, no translation. Therefore both reference frames are inertial reference frames. Furthermore both coordinate systems have their origin at the COM. Therefore they are identical!

Comment: @ftiaronsem  *"A week ago, I showed you that the angular momentum caused by the babys motion and the angular momentum due to the movement of the COM-P do not cancel, but sum up."* I think this is the greatest contradiction in our opinions. You showed nothing but missed the fact that in this movement the baby's motion is the sum of two components: (1) its motion relative the pad and (2) its motion with the pad. Only (1) contributes to the angular momentum of the system. The COM-P and the child as the whole move in such manner that the COM would remain stationary(conservation of linear momentum)

Comment: ...In this motion angular moments of the pad and child about the COM mutually cancel. There is no point to discuss further if we do not reach agreement on this matter.

Comment: @Martin: Allow me to cite myself: _Since the COM remains fixed, the pad and the child translate in opposite directions on the opposite side of the pad. Therefore they are rotating in the same direction and the angular momenta do not cancel._ You will realize by applying right hand rule, that the vector of the angular momentum of the child and the vector of the angular momentum of the COM-P are parallel. Therefore they sum up. In order to cancel they would have to be anti-parallel, which is not the case. Please show me the error in this reasoning.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: I agree that it is not easy to imagine movement of the child relative the ground. That's why i said that it is much more easy to consider the problem in the RF of the COM. We do not need to care about whether the COM remains fixed or moves in that case. But you still want to consider the problem in the RF of ground(water). Maybe it is easier to deal with formulas. I think you are agree that we can express the velocity of the child relative the ground as $\vec{v}_g=\vec{v}_p+\vec{v}_{rel}$. Here $\vec{v}_p$ is velocity of the pad relative the ground (because the pad performs...

Comment: ...translational motion its each particle has the same velocity $\vec{v}_p$). $\vec{v}_{rel}$ is the velocity of the child relative the pad. Now, the pad has relative the ground velocity $\vec{v}_p$ as well as child's velocity has a component equal to $\vec{v}_p$. Because the pad and child are located in opposite sides relative the COM it is obvious that their corresponding angular momentums cancel. These would sum up only if the child's velocity component would equal to $-\vec{v}_p$. So only component that contributes to the angular momentum of the system is $\vec{v}_{rel}$.

Comment: Your error is that you ignore child's velocity component $\vec{v}_p$.

Comment: @Martin: I am currently abroad and can't answer you from here. I will, as soon as I am back in Germany (around Wednesday/Thursday). Looking forward till then...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been busy lately. The Trick is that childs velocity indeed equals $-\vec{v}_p$ (if you define the COM-P velocity as $\vec{v}_p$). Look from the upper left  picture in this answer to the upper right picture. The child is moving in the direction of the positive x-axis, the COM-P in the direction of the negative x-Axis.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: You need not any picture in this case. This is the most basic thing you're incorrect. I have no longer anything to add. It seems to me that you've lost all rational thinking under the pressure of the reputation score of Mark and its up rated solution.

Comment: @Martin: You state _You need not any picture in this case._ and thats it. I think I have been pretty clear: The child is moving in the direction of the positive x-axis, the COM-P in the direction of the negative x-Axis. Therefore the childs velocity equals $-\vec{v}_p$ if  $\vec{v}_p$ is the velocity of the COM-P. Therefore both angular momenta add up! (Note that I am always talking about the motion of the COM-P. For the moment we are not considering the spinning of the pad)

Comment: @Martin: So please argue precisly, where the problem in the above chain of reasoning is. Do you think the motion depicted by the pictures is wrong? Do you think some conclusion I have drawn in the last comment is wrong? If so, please be precise!

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Ok, i rewrite again the formula for the velocity of the child relative the ground: $\vec{v}_g=\vec{v}_p+\vec{v}_{rel}$. We consider at the moment only component $\vec{v}_p$. This is the velocity of the pad relative the ground and it is a velocity component of the child relative the ground at the same time also. So you claim that $\vec{v}_p=-\vec{v}_p$ and $2=-2$ or $5=-5$ etc. ? What do you trust more, the picture or common sense ? It is a mystery for me, a complete mystery!

Comment: @Mark: While dealing with angular momentum, you have to think in terms of vectors. Note: The following part, assumes nothing about the general motion of the pad nor the child, it is based solemnly on considerations about the _instant_ the child is moving. For the sake of argument lets take the situation depicted in picture number one (we could choose any moment in time here, the principle remains the same). In Picture number one, the child is at postion $\vec{r_c}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0,5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$,

Comment: and the center of mass of the pad (COM-P) is at position $\vec{r_p}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ - 0,5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The velocity of the child at that instant is $\vec{v_c}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and the the velocity of the COM-P is $\vec{v_p}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now we use the definition of the angular momentum:

Comment: $L=\vec{r} \times m \vec{v}$. Let us assume that the child has a weight of 1kg (every mass would be ok here). Then $\vec{L_p} = \vec{r_p} \times \vec{v_p} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ - 0,5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ - 0,5 \end{pmatrix} $ and for the child one gets:

Comment: $\vec{L_c} = \vec{r_c} \times \vec{v_c} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0,5 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ - 0,5 \end{pmatrix}$. As you can see both, vectors point in the same direction. In order to get the total angular momentum one has to add the all the angular momenta, so $\vec{L}=\vec{L_p}+\vec{L_c} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ - 1 \end{pmatrix}$ which is obviously not zero. Therefore the angular momenta of the system add up. They do not cancel.

Comment: Why you believe something different is also a mystery to me. :-). I believe we are currently talking at cross purposes. If you were trying to convince me that the velocity of the child and the COM-P are the same by absolute value, I agree. But since the system is rotating around the COM, the vector of one velocity has a positve sign, while the vector of the other has a negative sign. This is what I tried to explain by saying that $v_c = - v_p$. I hope I could express my point.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: You have once again joined rotational and translational motions together. Remember, we consider only translational part of the movement of the system. Specifically, we ignore spinning of the pad(fortunately, you ignored that) and motion of child relative the pad. This last motion is a rotational motion and unfortunately you take this into account and will go to confuse yourself. It is much more easy to consider rotational and translational movement separately. So please consider only translational motion.

Comment: @Martin. If I understand you correct, you say that I am using the motion of the child relative the pad. I know that I am using the translational motion of the child relative the ground, but I do not see where I am using the translational motion of the child relative the pad. Please point out where I am doing this.

Comment: Furthermore you say that I joined rotational and translational motions together. Well, I somewhat disagree. I have to stress, that the above calculations are done for a specific moment in time. At such a moment, all the velocities are linear and treated as such. (Keep in mind that it is perfectly legal to calculate an angular momentum for linear motions.)

Comment: Moreover you seem to have quite a precise picture of the motion in mind. Can you calculate a small concrete example, like I did yesterday (I.e illustrate how you are going to solve the problem using only translational motions)?  Or can you even solve the entire problem the way you think it is correct? Hopefully ;-) I would be able to derive some contradiction.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: This is a really good idea. So far i have only attacked your solution. This led to nowhere so far. So let's exchange the roles now. I propose a correct solution, in my opinion, and you're going to attack it. Ok, i am using the reference frame of the center of mass of the system(in short: the RF of COM). In this system we do not need to care about translational motion of the system. All motions in this system are rotational. We have only one rotation axis now: the axis that passes through the COM. With this, the problem is solved now. The parallel axis theorem applies and we get...

Comment: ...the second solution you got(before Mark's solution).

Comment: @Martin. Ok, I perfectly agree that we have only rotational motions. In a plane each object has _two_ rotational-degrees of freedom. 1) Spinning around its own COM (like the daily rotation of the earth) 2) Orbiting around a fixed point (like the earth around the sun). Since we have two bodies here, we could theoretically have four degrees of freedom. If you apply the parallel axis theorem, there is just one degree of freedom. So you are fixing three degrees of freedom in your solution. Please justify why.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: *"In a plane each object has two rotational-degrees of freedom."* No, a rigid body has 3 degrees of freedom(DOF) on a plane: 2 translational DOF and 1 rotational DOF (Give me a reference that claims something else!). Note that in case of 2) you mentioned, only center of mass of the body is orbiting. It does not have anything to do with rotation of the body. Actually, your orbiting is classified as a translational motion. We can split it into translational motions along the x axis and y axis.

Comment: @Martin. Yeah, you are perfectly right about that. I just wanted to simplify things a bit. I put the 2 translational DOF together, since the x and y coordinate are always located on a circle and therefore correlated (of course this is only true in our case). If you apply it that way you would only have to consider four degrees of freedom. But take it as you like ;-), you are very much free too start with the six DOF and tell me why it is legitimate to fix five of them.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: Where do you see the presence of six DOF? We are on the RF of COM now. The system has 2 DOF. One belongs to the pad and another to the child. Both are rotational DOF. With this the system's position in the plane is uniquely defined. You should make it clear to yourself what the degree of freedom means.

Comment: @Martin: I think I am perfectly aware what a degree of freedom means. In theory there would be six degrees of freedom for a system in a plane consisting of two rigid bodies: $x_{pad},y_{pad},x_{child},y_{child},\omega_{pad},\omega_{child}$ Where $\omega$ is the angular displacement of the rigid body. This is what theory tells us. In our case many of these parameters are correlated and can be expressed by each other.

Comment: Now, in the solution with the parallel axis thoerem, there is just one degree of freedom, the angular displacement of the system $\omega_{system}$. In order for this solution to work, you would need to express all six coordinates above by $\omega_{system}$. I would like you to do that. Please reason for every parameter why and how you are doing that. :-)

Comment: @ftiaronsem: You are still on the reference frame of the ground. We are working in the reference frame of the center of mass of the system now. x,y components you mentioned describe translational motions. These motions determine the motion of the center of mass of the system. Since we are on the reference frame of the center of mass of the system these motions are unnecessary for us now. Is it really so hard to understand? :-)

Comment: @Martin: There are things you are overlooking. It is not that simple. I don't have the time now, I will explain this weekend...

Comment: @Martin: If I understand you correctly you suggest a rotating refrence frame, with its origin at the center of mass of the system. In the following I will list some problems, with this ansatz: 1) It is extremly difficult to express the total angular momentum of the system, since you can't measure the true velocities of the system-parts, but only their velocity relative to your rotating reference frame. 2) A rotating reference frame is an accelarted reference frame. Therefore one suffers from sheer forces.

Comment: One could be tempted to argue that they are not to be considered, since the COM-P and the child stay stationary. However this is not the case, otherwise the force that the baby is acting on the pad would have no effect. 3) In such a rotating reference fram one would have four theoretical degrees of freedom (not two!): $r_{baby},r_{com-p},\omega_{baby},\omega_{com-p}$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin and $\omega$ the angular displacement of the rigid bodies. Of course the two $r$ parameters are fixed and  $\omega_{baby}$ can be expressed by $\omega_{com-p}$.

Comment: So there is one effective degree of freedom, which would remain. In case you havn't ment a rotating reference frame, forget the part above. However a reference frame with its orign at the center of mass of the system which is not rotating would have to be stationary relative to the reference frame of the ground. In that case, you would have to consider all the free  parameters that are present in the reference frame of the ground.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: The reference frame of the center of mass of the system is not a rotating frame. It does not rotate around something. It is fixed relative the ground by definition.(conservation of linear momentum, this follows from the problem's description). May be the things are more clearer if we consider vectors. All vectors of linear(translational) motions are parallel to the plane. We are interested only in rotational motions whose vectors are perpendicular to the plane. The pad's rotation and the child's rotation. You do not need anything more.